# How to find the gender of my interviewer?

Tags: interviewing

I am being interviewed for a new role in a new company via a recruiter. The recruiter informed me that I will be interviewed by the CTO named Alex. Now Alex does not have a profile picture on his(hers?) LinkedIn and there is no gender pronoun on the emails exchanged.

How can I find their gender so that I can address them properly beforehand?

Comment: Under these circumstances, it's pretty reasonable to assume the interviewer prefers to be addressed as Alex. Or, you could ask the recruiter to find out for you.

Comment: Don't speak until spoken to? Why do you need to "address" somebody? Personally, I don't like it when people I barely know use my name, especially my first name.

Comment: I'm trying to understand the question. Are you planning to email Alex about how much you're looking forward to the interview, and don't know whether to say "Dear Sir" or 'Dear Madam"? Are you worried about entering the room and saying "nice to meet you sir" before suddenly realizing Alex isn't a sir? Or is it a matter or Mr/Ms Lastname? Please expand on "address them properly beforehand".

Comment: Why is this a question. Not a smart alec comment, either: Why does knowing this before hand matter? Are you writing a preliminary letter? I've always just gone to the interview and said "I have an interview with Alex" and wait for them to come out. When I meet them I say "Hello, I'm SliderBlackrose, pleasure to meet you" and move along. I don't address their gender, because it doesn't matter. If they haven't given you a last name, then you're not going to address them by a pronoun anyhow. After the interview it's still "Dear Alex: It was a pleasure..." Gender simply never entered into it.

Comment: Be aware the next time you address... Andrea!!!!!! :-)

Comment: Just ask them lul

Answer (score 40):

Here's how to proceed without knowing the gender of Alex. Avoid any terms that carry gender markers. If you want to email Alex, either just start right in to the body of the email without a salutation, or use "Dear Alex" or "Good morning". Don't refer to Mr Lastname or Ms Lastname, nor use honorifics like Sir or Madam.

This will have the following advantages beyond gender agnosticsm:

- it's simple, requiring no prior research, phone calls, or investigation
- it avoids being overly formal, even old fashioned (sir/madam, using lastname) to a person who has agreed to a recruiter presenting them informally
- it avoids screwing up on a title (Mrs/Miss/Ms can all be offensive to some people) or omitting a higher one such as Dr that the person actually prefers
- in the unlikely but possible event that Alex is nonbinary or otherwise rejects any of your possible pronouns and titles, it's the only safe choice

These benefits are in rough order of importance. I'd encourage you to take a look at why you need to know this one thing about a person before you can talk to them. You don't need to know their age, marital status, race, religion, ability to walk, see, or hear, so why do you need to know gender? Relax and address the person politely, in the ways we do when we don't know that piece of information.

Answer (score 14):

If this interview is arranged by a recruiter, why not ask the recruiter? It's very likely that the recruiter has either already met Alex or spoken to him/her before.

If you're being asked to talk to Alex before meeting him/her in person, like email or phone, and you want to be formal, I'm sure the recruiter won't think it's a strange question.

Answer (score 10):

> How can I find their gender so that I can address them properly
>   beforehand?

Call the front desk and ask.

I've called the front desk before to ask about lots of things before an interview - parking, full name, phone extension, etc. As long as you are pleasant and it doesn't sound fishy front desk personnel are usually very happy to help.

Comment: *Do* explain that you're asking because you have an interview coming up. (Don't be shy about that!) Otherwise they may think that you're yet another recruiter trying to fish for information or job leads, and they won't be as helpful.

Answer (score 7):

I agree with "Ask the recruiter.". The next issue is what to ask the recruiter.

I suggest "How should I address Alex?".

That will give you better information than you could have got from a photo or, as suggested in another answer, phone voice pitch. The recruiter should know, or be able to find out, whether Alex prefers given name or title-and-surname.

If Alex prefers title-and-surname the recruiter should be able to tell you what title to use. Just knowing gender does not tell you whether a man prefers "Dr." or "Mr.", or for a woman "Dr.", "Ms", "Mrs", or "Miss".